# NetworkImage( snapshot .data!), always refreshing when press something on dialog

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a FutureBuilder to load a snapShot from an image file. But every things is working till I open a dialog and try to type something in But when I press on a key the image is keeping refreshing like in the video. Ho can I fix it?

https://photos.app.goo.gl/f6CJALRdZxT9ABXYA

*as you can see in background the image keep refresh when I type something*

code:

```
                                      FutureBuilder(
                                            future: downloadURL(file),
                                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                                AsyncSnapshot<String>
                                                    snapshot) {
                                              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                                      ConnectionState.done &&
                                                  snapshot.hasData) {
                                                return Center(
                                                  child: CircleAvatar(
                                                    backgroundColor:
                                                        Colors
                                                            .transparent,
                                                    backgroundImage:
                                                        NetworkImage(
                                                            snapshot
                                                                .data!),
                                                    radius: 10.0,
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              }
                                              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                                      ConnectionState.waiting ||
                                                  snapshot.hasData) {
                                                return Container();
                                              }
                                              return Container();
                                            })


///Get download url
  Future<String> downloadURL(String file) async {
    try {
      String downloadURL = await storage.ref('images/$file').getDownloadURL();
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(downloadURL);
      return downloadURL;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e);
    }
    return downloadURL(file);
  }
```

Comment: Basically, the code is making API/firebase requests and the whole widget tree is getting updated. I would suggest you use cached_network_image library to cache the image or simply just create a different class (Stateless Widget) for CircleAvatar. It will solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

in your `StatefulWidget` class, define a `Future` method marked with late :

```
late Future methodWeGonnaUse;
```

then in the `initState`

```
@override
void initState() {
 methodWeGonnaUse  = downloadURL(file);
}
```

then in your `FutureBuilder`, assign the methodWeGonnaUse to the `future` property :

```
 FutureBuilder(
 future: methodWeGonnaUse,
 /* more code */
```

I will explain, that opening of the Keyboard and typing in some `TextField` will force the parent widgets should rebuild to adapt to the screen size changes (opening the keyboard change the size of the screen in your app), the `FutureBuilder` is just a widget so it will be also rebuilt, which cause a refresh for the `snapshot.data`

by assigning it a Future that's late, and that got another `Future` from the `initState` (which is called just on the initialize of the widget) will save that value, and calling `SetState(() {})` will not rebuild the `FutureBuidlder` again.

Comment: It's sya error = `Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.

Tried to infer 'dynamic' for 'T' which doesn't work:
  Parameter 'builder' declared as     'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<T>)'
                      but argument is 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<String>)'.
The type 'dynamic' was inferred from:
  Parameter 'future' declared as     'Future<T>?'
                     but argument is 'Future<dynamic>'.

Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.

`

Comment: And I get the error `LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'methodWeGonnaUse' has not been initialized.)` as well